# Find norm of linear operator subordinate to Euclid norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be the linear operator in the space $V=\mathbb R^2$ with action 
$(x,y)\to(\frac{x}{2},\frac{-y}{3})$.
I have to find the norm of this operator subordinate to Euclid norm ($p=2$).

1. I found the matrix of operator.
2. I found square of the matrix of operator.

What should I do next?
By definion of norm, I find the sup of norm after operator action and divide by norm before?
Is the answer is $\frac{1}{6}$?
Sorry for terrible english.

Comment: What does this operator map (1, 0) to? Clearly this is bigger than 1/6?

Comment: @Vim to (1/2, 0)

Comment: So, your point is that I should find combination of x and y values, which gives the max norm value or? I found that Euclid norm of matrix is the square root of max eigen value of A*A(T), where T is transposed matrix

Comment: I think I got it. I have two eigen values 1/4 and 1/9, so the square root of the biggest is 1/2. So the norm is 1/2? @Vim

Comment: eigenvalues are just 1/2 and -1/3, not squared.

Comment: In general the 2-norm of a matrix is its largest singular value: $$\|A\|_2 = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \sqrt{x^T A^T A x} = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \sqrt{x^T Q^T \Lambda Q x} =\sup_{\|z\|=1} z^T \Lambda z=\lambda_{\max}$$ in which $Q^T\Lambda Q$ is the orthonormal decomposition of $A^T A$.

Comment: Thank you for enlightening, man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator norm is defined as $\sup \{\|A(x,y)\|: \|(x,y)|| \leq 1\}$. This is then supremum of the numbers $\sqrt {\frac {x^{2}} 4+\frac {y^{2}} 9}$ over $(x,y)$ such that $x^{2} +y^{2} \leq 1$. The maximum  value is attained when $x=1, y=0$ and the maximum value is $\frac  1 2$. So the norm is $\frac  1 2$.